# Sails.js: policy specific for socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, acl, sails.js

I've build a backend for an app using sailsjs. My app uses some kind of token based authentication, for which I've set up a policy:

```
module.exports.policies = {

    // Policies that apply to all controllers.
    // '*': true // DEV ONLY
    '*': [ 'requestData' ],

    'UserController': {
        '*': [ 'requestData' ],
        'register': true,
        'exists': true
    },

    'AdminController': {
        '*': true
    }

};
```

That works great. However, now I want to access the protected controllers from a view in my `AdminController`, using `Socket.IO`. But, as expected, `Forbidden` is thrown when I try to access a list of resources from my view.

Is it possible to define a policy in which:
- all requests (`http` or `websocket`) from the same domain are allowed
- all requests from any other domain are not allowed

Furthermore, even if it is possible, is this approach safe? I own the entire server and domain, so in normal circumstances no other apps will be served from this server.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you're getting "forbidden" when accessing a route under `/admin` via sockets?  That shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @ScottGress no, I'm trying to access the REST routes for my other controllers, using sockets, from a view under `/admin`. E.g.: `socket.get('/request', function(data) {});`. But, since those controllers are under a special policy requiring a token, I'm stuck (I could of course, make a special token for all GET actions that is hardcoded into the client-side javascript.. But that would constitute a security risk)..

Answer (score -1):

**Please share your sails.js version when asking questions!**

For those interested in the general problem of applying policies to sockets: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1229

For those interested in authentication over sockets see below (it's a related issue, linked from the above issue as well):
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1348